# Low GPU utilization when training PyTorch Model on HPC server, but no issues on personal computer

Tags: performance, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, fine-tuning

I'm currently retraining/fine-tuning a visual transformer model (which was pretrained on ImageNet) on Cifar10.
Unfortunately I have problems understanding the performance of the System.
On my personal PC (ryzen 5 processor, ssd drive and rtx 3070) one training epoch takes around 8 minutes. However on the HPC system with 8 cores of a Xeon Processor and a A100-40GB one epoch takes 12-14 minutes.

I already added the PyTorch profiler to debug the issue, unfortunately the breakdown only tells me that the GPU is busy with "other" things.

My PC summary:
[image: GPU summary of PC (93% util)]

The HPC summary:
[image: GPU summary of HPC (12% util)]

Interestingly they both have a similar achieved occupancy and Compute ability but i don't know how to interpret these metrics.

I already tried every trick from the Optimization book:

- batch size. i tried every batch size between 32 and 4096, but it makes no difference (currently i have batch size of 32 on the PC and 512 on the HPC system)
- Automatic mixed precision: bfloat16 AMP is activated in the forward cast
- DataLoader: i use the pytorch dataloader without shuffling and 4 workers
- Data locality: i copy the data to the node-local ssd before the training starts so it is already present
- removing almost all cpu-gpu synchronization code (`.cpu()`)

For reference:

This is my dataloading code:

```py
def load_cifar10_local_torchvision(
    processor: ViTImageProcessor,  # for the normalization, rezising, etc.
    data_dir: str,  # location of cifar dataset (always SSD drive)
    split: Literal["val", "validation", "train", "test"] = "train",
    batch_size: int = 16,
) -> Tuple[pt.DataLoader, pt.Dataset, int]:
    dataset = CIFAR10(root=data_dir, train=split != "test", download=False)

    if split == "val" or split == "validation":
        _, dataset = pt.random_split(dataset, lengths=[0.8, 0.2])
    elif split == "train":
        dataset, _ = pt.random_split(dataset, lengths=[0.8, 0.2])

    def collate(batch):
        inputs = processor.preprocess(
            images=[x[0].convert("RGB") for x in batch], return_tensors="pt"
        )
        inputs["labels"] = torch.as_tensor([item[1] for item in batch])
        return inputs

    data_loader = pt.DataLoader(
        dataset,
        collate_fn=collate,
        pin_memory=True,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        drop_last=False,
        num_workers=NUM_WORKERS,  # numworkers = 4
        shuffle=False,
    )

    return data_loader, dataset, 10
```

The training loop looks as follows:

```py
def train_epoch(self) -> Tuple[float, Dict]:
        """
        run training for one epoch.
        Also calculates the average loss and other metrics for the epoch and return it
        """
        prof = logger.tb_profiler("prof_train_epoch")
        prof.start()
        metrics = self._load_metrics()
        running_loss = 0.0
        total = 0
        self.model.train()
        for batch in self.train_dl:
            images = batch["pixel_values"].to(
                self.device, memory_format=t.channels_last, non_blocking=True
            )
            labels = batch["labels"].to(self.device, non_blocking=True)

            with t.autocast(
                device_type=str(self.device),
                dtype=self.amp_type,
                enabled=self.use_amp,
                cache_enabled=True,
            ):
                outputs = self.model(
                    pixel_values=images, labels=labels, interpolate_pos_encoding=True
                )
                loss = outputs.loss

            # all the steps
            self.scaler.scale(loss).backward()
            self.scaler.step(self.optim)
            self.scaler.update()
            prof.step()

            # reset gradients - be wary of different behaviours with none
            self.optim.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
            self.model.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)

            predictions = t.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=-1)
            running_loss += loss
            total += predictions.size(0)
            metrics.add_batch(
                predictions=predictions,
                references=labels,
                logits=outputs.logits.tolist(),
            )

        loss = (running_loss / total).detach().cpu().item()
        prof.stop()
        return loss, metrics.compute()
```

I'm puzzled why the same code with almost the same settings runs so bad on the HPC.

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: The data is usually stored on a slow network drive, but the compute nodes themselves have SSDs where i copy the dataset to before the training.
I just experimented around and found out that with the torchvision "FakeData" dataset, which generates noise to be used as the input, and the utilization is fine. This way I can train almost 50000 samples per minute. So the issue seems to be the dataloader or I/O performance. But i dont understand it as cifar10 is a very small dataset and memory pinning is turned on.

The profiler unfortunately does not tell what other could mean

Comment: The profiler output shows "dataloader" at 0, so if the profiler can be trusted, the root cause does not seem to be there.